# Why the following loop is not looping on other staffid?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I want to generate a monthly report for a branch that have multiple number of staff

I have this `staffid '275,222,278'`, but the result is only showing staffid 275, seems like the `set @staff = @staff+1` is not working.

However, if I change this line to `set @staffid := (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@staffID, ',', @staff),',',-1))` , I hardcode the `@staff` for example to 2, will show the data of staff 222 and if hardcode to 3 will show data of staff 278

Below is the loop function in a stored procedure

```
set @staffID := '275,222,278';
set @countstaff := (LENGTH(@staffID) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@staffID, ',', '')) + 1);
set @staff := 1;

WHILE @staff <= @countstaff
DO
    set @staffid := (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@staffID, ',', @staff),',',-1));
    set @loanID := (select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from sharing_profit where sharing_profit=@staffid);
    
    set @dataArr =  (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(x) FROM
        (SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
            @staffid,get_revenuestamprepayment31(@staffid,YEAR_,MONTH_,@loanID)
        ) as x) AS tbl);
                    
    set @totalrows = (select JSON_LENGTH(@dataArr));
    if @totalrows is null then 
        set @err := 'RecordNotFound';
        LEAVE MyScope;
    end if;
        
    set @staff = @staff+1;
    
END WHILE;
```

The result is this without showing the other staffid

```
    "275": [
      {
        "07": [
          {
            "stamp": {
              "tepi": null,
              "account": null
            },
            "revenue": {
              "tepi": null,
              "account": 5445
            },
            "fullname": "ss2",
            "staff_id": 275,
            "staff_code": "3143414342ss2"
          }
```

What is wrong with the above loop?

Comment: could be please be more accurate about the data structure?

Comment: @ChristianFelix I am only getting one data of a staff...   I want to get all staff data, not only staffid 275, but 278 and 222 as well

Comment: could you paste the table data for those 3 entry?

Comment: You don't need to use `SELECT` in your `SET` statements if you're not querying a table. Just `SET @staffid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(...)`

Comment: Each time through the loop you replace `@dataarr`, so at the end it just contains the result from the last query.

Comment: @Barmar , but still the result is only showing the staffid on the first position, not on the last position

Comment: I noticed that, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're redefining the `@staffid` variable here:

```
    set @staffid := (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@staffID, ',', @staff),',',-1));
```

So the next time through the loop, it can't get the next ID from the list, because now `@staffid` just contains the first ID.

Use a different variable `@cur_staffid`.

Comment: How to make the @dataArr giving all data of all staff?  SInce now is only giving one staff only

Comment: Instead of doing a loop, do a single where with `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(sharing_profit, @staffid)`, and combine all the results with `JSON_OBJECTAGG()`.